# WPF - Showing specific data for Grid on case of using window style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have providing a windows style for all of my windows:
Here is what I adding on app.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="Style.Window.Default" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid Name="gridBar" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,0,1,0">
                        <Grid.Background>

                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0" EndPoint="0, 1" Opacity=".1">
                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
                                <GradientStop Offset=".3" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Grid.Background>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <!-- title -->
                        <ItemsControl Background="Transparent" MouseDoubleClick="MaximizeClick"  >
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="8,8,8,0" x:Name="txtTitle"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ModernWindowTitle}"
                                      />
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="top"   Margin="0,40,0,0" Background="White">

                    </Grid>
                </Grid>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here is what I have on each window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Height="300" Width="300"  Title="title"
         Style="{StaticResource Style.Window.Default}" >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="text of window 1"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How could I change my code for having or showing data of Grid, because it's not showing data of the Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a content presenter to insert the content in the ControlTemplate. You never say where you want the content to appear, but this top-aligned grid is empty so maybe that's where?

```
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="top"   Margin="0,40,0,0" Background="White">
                    <ContentPresenter
                        />
                </Grid>
```

I have a question for you: What is the purpose of the ItemsControl here?

```
                    <!-- title -->
                    <ItemsControl Background="Transparent" MouseDoubleClick="MaximizeClick"  >
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" Margin="8,8,8,0" x:Name="txtTitle"
                                Style="{StaticResource ModernWindowTitle}"
                                  />
                    </ItemsControl>
```

Another question: Why do you define four columns in your grid and never use any of them? What are those columns for?

Comment: I have deleting them for showing main part of code on StackOverFlow.